# Javascript: ISO Conversion to Shortform of month

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date value that looks like this:
2015-07-12T22:00:00.000Z

I want to convert this into the short form string of the monthly value e.g. "Jan"
Can someone give me a hint at how I could go about this?

Comment: Thanks, Rob. I've edited this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to get the month number, use it to get the month name, then replace the number with the name in the string, e.g.:

```
function insertMonthAbbr(s) {
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                  'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var monthNumber = s.substring(5,7);
    return s.substring(0,5) + months[monthNumber-1] + s.substring(7);
}

console.log(insertMonthAbbr('2015-07-12T22:00:00.000Z')); // 2015-Jul-12T22:00:00.000Z
```

No need for Date methods.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, Rob!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in that ISO string to the Date constructor as such:

`new Date('2015-07-12T22:00:00.000Z')`

This would result in `Sun Jul 12 2015 15:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

From here, you can do a few different things.

You can convert it into a string, split the string up into an array and call the second element (that has the month) as such:

`new Date('2015-07-12T22:00:00.000Z').toDateString().split(' ')[1]`

Alternately, you can create a hash of months and use Date.getMonth() to map to it.

Comment: It's not very efficient to start with a precisely formatted string, convert it a Date, then convert it to an implementation–dependent string. The OP is then in a worse position than they started. Much easier just to modify the original string. ;-) Also, a good number of browsers in use will not parse the OP format.

Comment: Very true. I like your solution more.